# Python: how to print n lines above current cursor position (above current line)

Tags: python, stdout

Suppose I have

```
print("line1")
print("line2")
print("\n\n line3")
```

and now I would like to print a "line4" over "line2".

How can I do it in python using only the `print` function?

Comment: Why did you rolled-back the edit (if I may ask)?

Comment: Why did you change my title? I want to make it clear in the title that it is Python.

Comment: That's what tags are for... See: [removing words from titles because they're in the tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251859/removing-words-from-titles-because-theyre-in-the-tags) and [should questions include tags in their titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ANSI escape sequences: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) [realpython](https://realpython.com/lessons/ansi-escape-sequences/)

The CSI (control sequence introducer) in python is `\033[`

So for example, you could use the Cursor Up (CUU) sequence which is the CSI followed by `{n}A` where `n` is the number of times you want the cursor to move up.

So by defining

```
def cursorup(n):
    print(f"\r\033[{n}A", end="")
```

either

```
print("line1")
print("line2")
print("\n\n line3")
cursorup(3)
print("line4")
```

or

```
print("line1")
print("line2")
print("\n\n line3")
print("\r\033[3A", end="")
print("line4")
```

will work.

The `\r` is to do a carriage return and move the cursor to the beginning of the current line. While `end=""` is so that the print function doesn't go to a new line after printing.

Comment: Thank you. Does this work in Windows CMD?

Comment: I don't know. I use Linux.

Answer (score 0):

One way to write output in arbitrary locations is with another library such as `curses`.

Comment: @patapouf_ai Nope. I suggest you google "python curses" to do some research.